# How to resolve unauthenticated issue in Postman GET Request

Tags: laravel, api, postman

I used Laravel-8 for rest api. The route is shown below:

```
localhost:8888/myapp/server/api/v1/admin/role
```

It is a GET Request.

When I send it on POSTMAN, I got this error:

> 401Unauthorized

> {
> "message": "Unauthenticated."
> }

In my route I have:

> 'middleware' => ['auth:api']]

The reason is because I don't know how to add the Login details. email: akwetey@gmail.com, password: mypass

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: The login details are entered in the form. or in json format.

Comment: @HassaanAli - I can't see that. Kindly guide. Thanks

Comment: please provide some more details of your code  and a screen shot of your postman request...it would be more helpful to give an answer...

Comment: laravel gives token when you try to authenticate. It's done using `post` and the data is sent in `raw (json/text)` format.

Comment: you could better have a look at this...https://www.positronx.io/laravel-rest-api-with-passport-authentication-tutorial/

Answer (score 4):

This person walks you through the process nicely and should get you setup.
https://coding-lesson.com/api-authentication-with-laravel-passport/

Basically you need to:

1. Get to your login api, probably something like: localhost:8888/myapp/server/api/v1/login
2. Create a POST request to the login API, select the Body tab and define key values for you Email and Password
3. Then run the request and copy the AccessToken value from the results
4. Now with your API above, select the Authorization tab, choose Bearer Token as the Type and paste in your AccessToken value for the Token field
5. You should also go to your Headers table and define Accept and Content-Type keys, both with values of: application/json

Of course you'll want to then change all this to use variables after you get it right, so you don't have to keep repeating this with all your new API calls.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch data behind protected routes you need to provide a token that will verify that the user who made the call is authenticated.

Then you have to provide the token in Authorization section of postman.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know the difference between `Post` and `Get`. Laravel works a little different then regular `PHP`, let me tell you how.

1. In order to access the protected routes you'll have to first access the token from `login` route. By sending the required data in [image: Json Format].
2. Once that's done it'll return the token which can be used to access the protected routes under `admin` or `auth` middleware.

In your case you're accessing `localhost:8888/myapp/server/api/v1/admin/role` which is a protected route under `admin` middleware. You'll have to first access `token` and then send `token` with the get request to fetch the required data.